# Can I create a mobile website from an existing hybrid mobile app in IBM MobileFirst 6.3?

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a hybrid mobile app developed using IBM MobileFirst 6.3 platform. Is there a way I can provide it as a mobile website? Does MobileFirst provide an out-of-the-box way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is called the Mobile Web environment. The web app resources reside on the MobileFirst Server and are served as a website, a URL, that you will provide to your mobile users.

Please read the user documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/mobile%20web?scope=SSHS8R_6.3.0